# How to remove CDATA tags from any string with javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `angularjs` to fetch  `json` data from a `rest` webservice.

Problem: most text elements come preformated containing `html` tags like `<p>, <br>, <ul>` etc. As an indicator for these tags, the texts are wrapped inside a CDATA tag as follows:

json:

```
{
    "offerName": "<![CDATA[<b>Testoffer 1</b>]]>"
}
```

angularjs:

```
$http.get(url).success(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
});
```

html:

```
<h1>{{data.offerName}}</h1>
```

Now, how could I let the clientside remove any CDATA tags before they are shown?

Comment: Something like `.replace('<![CDATA[', '').replace(']]', '');` or something CDDATA/angular/json specific?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regular expression:

```
'<![CDATA[<b>Testoffer]]> 1</b>]]>'.replace(/^<\!\[CDATA\[|\]\]>$/g,'')
```

It only matches the the CDATA if they are at the start and end of the string. Remove the ^ and $ to match anywhere