# Remove <> symbols from CDATA XML tag using regex

Tags: regex, xml, xml2js

Lets say I have an XML document like this:

```xml
<records>
    <record>
        <name>Jon</name>
        <surname>Doe</surname>
        <dob>2001-02-01</dob>
        <comment>
            <![CDATA[[ Patient with > 2 and < 5 siblings]]]>
        </comment>
    </record>
    <record>
        <name>Jane</name>
        <surname>Doe</surname>
        <dob>2001-02-01</dob>
        <comment>
            <![CDATA[[ Patient with > 2 siblings ]]]>
        </comment>
    </record>
</records>
```

I need to convert this document to a JSON object using `xml2js`, but I need to remove the `<` and `>` symbols for it to avoid breaking the JSON conversion process.

**What I have tried**

Since I understand that I need to remove these symbols *before* passing the XML string to the `xml2js` parser I have tried variations of the solutions described in the following cases:

- [How to remove CDATA tags from any string with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31880031/how-to-remove-cdata-tags-from-any-string-with-javascript)
- [What regex will match text excluding what lies within HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179779/what-regex-will-match-text-excluding-what-lies-within-html-tags)
- [I need a regex that matches CDATA elements in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681861/i-need-a-regex-that-matches-cdata-elements-in-html)

I am successfull in matching the entire contents of the `CDATA` tag but not able to match the specific characters that I need to remove. This has to be accomplished in a single `regex` so I can pass it to the XML to JSON parser.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Additional Info**

Adding this since the question was voted down due to lack of research evidence.

I tried modifying a regex rule I found in one of the references I mentioned. This is the rule.

```regex
\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]>`
```

This matches the entire contents of teh CDATA tag. This is helpful, but what I need to to replace/remove content *within* the CDATA tags. Here is how it looks on the regex editor.

[image]

I then proceeded to modify the rule to match either `<` or `>` Here is the rule that I tried.

```regex
\[CDATA\[(.*?)[<>]*\]\]>
```

This rule matches the following content (not just the <> signs).

```
    [ Patient with > 2 and < 5 siblings]
```

Here is how it looks on the regex editor.

[image]

I hope this give more clarity about what I am trying to accomplish.

**Edit 2:**

Here is the error triggered by the code. The relevant error message is `invalid closing tag`.

[image]

Here is line 38 of `import.js` as referenced in the error trace.

```
const jsonXml = await parseStringPromise(xml).then((res) => res);
```

This line uses `xml2js` to parse the XML document and convert it to a JSON object. Because the CTAG contains the `<>` symbols, I assume that the parser thinks it is part of an XML tag that is not closed properly.

Comment: In what way does your conversion break? Isn't `comment: ["\n            [ Patient with > 2 and < 5 siblings]\n        "]` the content you expect?

Comment: Hey, I am in the process of editing the question to show what I have tried. I have considered two options:

1) Remove the <> symbos all together
2) Convert them to HTML entities

The XM to JSON conversion breaks because the XML tags use theses symbols. I am looking for ways to handle these cases.

Comment: Are you trying to process the XML document directly with regex? If so, why is this tagged `xslt`?  -- P.S. Do not  try to process the XML document directly with regex - see here why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454

Comment: Please show your code using that library and the result you get versus the one you want or explain in which way the "conversion breaks", which error you get.

Comment: Hello @michael.hor257k. I tagged the question as XSL because this XML file will be styled by an XSL stylesheet. However, the problem is not XSL related Apologies for that.

Martin, will edit question with request info in a few minutes.

Comment: Finished editing the question with the requested data. I really appreciate your time in helping with my question. @michael.hor257k

Comment: If you are using PCRE: `(?:\G(?!^)|<!\[CDATA\[\[)(?:(?!<!\[CDATA\[\[|]]>)[^<>])*\K[<>]`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MCn44x/1/).

Comment: You should address this to Martin Honnen. I know nothing about `xml2js`. The only thing I can tell you that your input is a well-formed XML document and if your tool cannot handle it properly then your tool is broken. You might want to try and pre-process the XML by applying an XSLT  *identity transform* to it; this will convert the CDATA sections to escaped text (i.e.  `Patient with &gt; 2 and &lt; 5 siblings`) which  your tool might be able to handle properly. But ultimately your best choice, IMHO, is to use another method to get the wanted result. Such as XSLT, for example.

Comment: Thanks Michael. This process happens before the XSLT stylesheet comes into play. I will submit an issue on the `xml2js` repository. Thanks to all for the feedback

Comment: Hey @WiktorStribiżew, thanks for the solution. Unfortunately, this has to work with Javascript (EMACScript)

Comment: Well, that is still [easy](https://regex101.com/r/MCn44x/2/), use `(?<=<!\[CDATA\[\[(?:(?!<!\[CDATA\[\[|]]>).)*)[<>]`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the parsing problem (using the current version of the library, 0.4.23):

```
var xml2js = require("xml2js")

var xml = `<records>
    <record>
        <name>Jon</name>
        <surname>Doe</surname>
        <dob>2001-02-01</dob>
        <comment>
            <![CDATA[[ Patient with > 2 and < 5 siblings]]]>
        </comment>
    </record>
    <record>
        <name>Jane</name>
        <surname>Doe</surname>
        <dob>2001-02-01</dob>
        <comment>
            <![CDATA[[ Patient with > 2 siblings ]]]>
        </comment>
    </record>
</records>`;

const jsResult = await xml2js.parseStringPromise(xml).then((res) => res);

const jsonResult = JSON.stringify(jsResult);

console.dir(jsonResult);
```

That gives

```
{"records":{"record":[{"name":["Jon"],"surname":["Doe"],"dob":["2001-02-01"],"comment":["\n            [ Patient with > 2 and < 5 siblings]\n        "]},{"name":["Jane"],"surname":["Doe"],"dob":["2001-02-01"],"comment":["\n            [ Patient with > 2 siblings ]\n        "]}]}}
```

which validates and formats fine at jsonlint.com as

```
{
    "records": {
        "record": [{
            "name": ["Jon"],
            "surname": ["Doe"],
            "dob": ["2001-02-01"],
            "comment": ["\n            [ Patient with > 2 and < 5 siblings]\n        "]
        }, {
            "name": ["Jane"],
            "surname": ["Doe"],
            "dob": ["2001-02-01"],
            "comment": ["\n            [ Patient with > 2 siblings ]\n        "]
        }]
    }
}
```

or you can use `const jsonResult = JSON.stringify(jsResult, null, 4);` also giving a readable output

```
{
    "records": {
        "record": [{
            "name": ["Jon"],
            "surname": ["Doe"],
            "dob": ["2001-02-01"],
            "comment": ["\n            [ Patient with > 2 and < 5 siblings]\n        "]
        }, {
            "name": ["Jane"],
            "surname": ["Doe"],
            "dob": ["2001-02-01"],
            "comment": ["\n            [ Patient with > 2 siblings ]\n        "]
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Martin. A noted by you previously, this issue has  more to do with badly formed XML than an issue with the library. The example given is a contrived case created by me as I cannot put the entire XML message due to privacy concerns. Again, the xml2js library handles this cases as expected. This is not a library isue.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, as it is the language you are using to code, you can use

```js
const text = `<comment>
   <![CDATA[[ Patient with > 2 and < 5 siblings]]]>
</comment>`
const re = /\[CDATA\[\[[^]*?]]>/g
console.log( text.replace(re, (x) => x.replace(/[<>]/g, '')) )
```

The `\[CDATA\[\[[^]*?]]>` pattern (see [its demo](https://regex101.com/r/aNaatU/1)) matches all `CDATA` blocks, even if they span multiple lines because

- `\[CDATA\[\[` matches `[CDATA[[` substrings
- `[^]*?` matches zero or more chars as few as possible
- `]]>` matches `]]>`.

Then, once the match is found, all `<` and `>` are removed from these matched texts with `x.replace(/[<>]/g, '')`.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing an answer to the question using *Wiktor Stribiżew* in case this helps anyone with a similar problem.

```regex
(?<=<!\[CDATA\[\[(?:(?!<!\[CDATA\[\[|]]>).)*)[<>]
```

Thanks *Wiktor*